# What is the best way to iterate through an array in Classic Asp VBScript?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, vbscript

In the code below

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
```

What is the point in asking using `LBound`? Surely that is always 0.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Why not use `For Each`?  That way you don't need to care what the `LBound` and `UBound` are.

```
Dim x, y, z
x = Array(1, 2, 3)

For Each y In x
    z = DoSomethingWith(y)
Next
```

Comment: You cannot use `For Each` to directly edit array cells, since `y` in your example is a copy of array cell, not it's reference. For array editing, `For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)` will allow one to refer to cell directly using `arr(i)` and edit cell content (like `arr(i) = Trim(arr(i))`).

Answer (score 21):

There is a good reason **NOT TO USE `For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)`**

`dim arr(10)` allocates eleven members of the array, 0 through 10 (assuming the VB6 default Option Base).

Many VB6 programmers assume the array is one-based, and never use the allocated `arr(0)`. We can remove a potential source of bug by using `For i = 1 To UBound(arr)` or `For i = 0 To UBound(arr)`, because then it is clear whether `arr(0)` is being used.

`For each` makes a copy of each array element, rather than a pointer.

This has two problems.

1. When we try to assign a value to an array element, it doesn't reflect on original. This code assigns a value of 47 to the variable `i`, but does not affect the elements of `arr`.

   ```
   arr = Array(3,4,8)
   for each i in arr
        i = 47
   next i
   Response.Write arr(0) '- returns 3, not 47
   ```
2. We don't know the index of an array element in `for each`, and we are not guaranteed the sequence of elements (although it seems to be in order).

Comment: Why would VB6 programmers assume the array is one-based? Zero-based is the default for arrays in VB6, unless specified otherwise with the `Option Base` statement or by explicitly defining a lower boundary when declaring the array. I prefer to use `LBound` because of the fact that it may not always be 0 (although as noted by AnthonyWJones, in VBS it almost always would be). But I would argue that it's bad practice to have a zero-based array and not use the allocated `arr(0)` (and thus we shouldn't have to assume somebody did that). I do agree with the arguments against using `For Each` though.

Answer (score 4):

`LBound` may not always be 0.

Whilst it is not possible to create an array that has anything other than a 0 Lower bound in VBScript, it is still possible to retrieve an array of variants from a COM component which may have specified a different `LBound`.

That said I've never come across one that has done anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it comes from VB6. Because with [Option Base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(VS.60).aspx) statement in VB6, you can alter the lower bound of arrays like this:

```
Option Base 1
```

Also in VB6, you can alter the lower bound of a specific array like this:

```
Dim myArray(4 To 42) As String
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always used For Each loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

```
dim arrFormaA(15)
arrFormaA( 0 ) = "formaA_01.txt"
arrFormaA( 1 ) = "formaA_02.txt"
arrFormaA( 2 ) = "formaA_03.txt"
arrFormaA( 3 ) = "formaA_04.txt"
arrFormaA( 4 ) = "formaA_05.txt"
arrFormaA( 5 ) = "formaA_06.txt"
arrFormaA( 6 ) = "formaA_07.txt"
arrFormaA( 7 ) = "formaA_08.txt"
arrFormaA( 8 ) = "formaA_09.txt"
arrFormaA( 9 ) = "formaA_10.txt"
arrFormaA( 10 ) = "formaA_11.txt"
arrFormaA( 11 ) = "formaA_12.txt"
arrFormaA( 12 ) = "formaA_13.txt"
arrFormaA( 13 ) = "formaA_14.txt"
arrFormaA( 14 ) = "formaA_15.txt"

Wscript.echo(UBound(arrFormaA))
''displays "15"

For i = 0 To UBound(arrFormaA)-1
    Wscript.echo(arrFormaA(i))
Next
```

Hope it helps.